# Batch file help please with if exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, backup

We have this printer management software that comes with built-in backup/restore command to backup its database.

And I need to create a batch file that will:

1a. check if folder name `OLD` exist on `C:\mybackup\`

1b. if it does then remove the folder and the contents, then

2a. check if `C:\mybackup\*.bak` exist

2b. if it does then create a folder called `OLD` in `C:\mybackup\`

2c. then move `C:\mybackup\*.bak` to `C:\mybackup\OLD`

then run backup command which creates multiple `.bak` files on `C:\mybackup\`

3. `scBackup64.exe -b C:\mybackup\` exit

I can only think of the commands, I wonder how to wrap it up with `IF THEN ELSE` or `IF EXIST`

```
@echo off
RD /S /Q C:\mybackup\OLD
MKDIR C:\mybackup\OLD
MOVE /Y C:\mybackup\*.bak C:\mybackup\OLD
scBackup64.exe -b C:\mybackup\
```

Comment: The commands are correct. You don't really have to wrap it inside an if-else. RD would fail if OLD is missing. batch file will continue. Effectively, whether the folder existed or not, after RD command, it will vanish. You don't really need an if-else here. At the most, suppress the error by redirecting to nul. `RD /S /Q C:\mybackup\OLD 2>nul` Similarly for move command.

Comment: thank you, so with 2>nul it will continue running the command even there is error ?

Comment: it will continue anyway. 2>nul just redirects the errormessage to nirwana.

Comment: @bickyz: yes, you are correct. I am assuming that you have permissions to do what you are trying to do. So practically, the only error `RD` would encounter is "no such directory found". Similarly, assuming that you CAN move `*.bak` to `OLD` directory, only error thrown would be `file not found`. The other possible errors in this case would be some ".bak file is in use, locked, cannot be moved". But, I am assuming that you can indeed move all the .bak files, if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `IF ELSE` statement to handle backup versions.

```
IF EXIST C:\mybackup\OLD\1.bak (ren C:\mybackup\OLD\1.bak.old) ELSE goto backup
:backup
MOVE /Y C:\mybackup\*.bak C:\mybackup\OLD
scBackup64.exe -b C:\mybackup\
```

ALso, you can include two commands for the IF statement.  `IF EXIST C:\mybackup\OLD\1.bak (ren C:\mybackup\OLD\1.bak.old && copy C:\mybackup\OLD\1.bak.old C:\mybackup\OLD2\1.bak.old) ELSE goto backup`